# python importing psycopg2 error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: the specified module could not be found

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to import the library `psycopg2` but I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject\fromSMStoDB\app.py", line 2, in 
> import psycopg2
> File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psycopg2_*init*_.py", line 51, in 
> from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: the specified module could not be found.

I am using python version: `3.10.0` and as editor, I am using VS code.

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  Python 3.10.0, pip 21.2.4.  When I installed psycopg2 v2.9.1, there was no wheel available, so pip built it from source.  I did not get any build errors.  This version of psycopg2 does not explicitly state it's valid for Python 3.10 -- not surprising since 3.10 just came out this week.

Comment: so yo think that changing the python interpreter to an oldest version like 3.9/8 will make it work?

Comment: If using a different python version is an option for you, then yes, I think that will work.  psycopg2 officially supports those other python versions.